# How does this curl command differ from my php code?

Tags: php, curl

I am simply trying to duplicate this curl command in PHP:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u username:password https://api.company.com/api/path
```

This is the PHP code I am using:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.company.com/api/path");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);  // $response is null
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);   // $info['http_code'] is 400
```

While my shell command is successful and I get data back from the server, this PHP code fails -- the server returns a 400 error. As far as I know, the PHP code and the shell command are effectively identical, so what's the difference I am missing?

---

**Edit:**

Here is the info I get from verbose mode:

```
* About to connect() to api.company.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* connected
* Connected to api.company.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    [...]
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /api/path HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic [...]
Host: api.company.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: -1
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: Close
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

---

**Edit 2**

I tried adding the following to the script:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

But this did not change the server's response.

Comment: Can you get any error information from the remote server? That should be your very first step

Comment: Can you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE)` as well and check?

Comment: @KaranAshar: I've just added the result of that to the end of the question.

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);`

Comment: @subroutines: Thanks for the idea; unfortunately I get the same response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the missing piece. I needed to explicitly set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to null:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
```

After adding that line, things now work just as they did with the shell command.